# How to choose pdf file from android storage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a pdf file from my android storage, but everytime it returns null.
It already works with image files, but when i try to get a pdf file it always returns null.
I'm already able to select the pdf file. On onActivityResult i'm able to get the uri from data, but the path is wrong ("content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A140"), so i'm trying to get the full path using `getPath` method, but like i said before, it always returns null.

This code must work with android version >= Android 6.0 (Sdk 23).

```java
private void selecionarArquivo() {
        boolean marshmallow = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22;
        boolean validate;
        if (marshmallow) {
            String permissions[] = new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
            validate = PermissionUtils.validate(getActivity(), 0, permissions);
        } else {
            validate = true;
        }
        if (validate) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // tipo can be application/pdf or image/*
            intent.setType(tipo); 
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_SELECIONAR_ARQUIVO);
        } else {
            AlertUtils.alert(getActivity(), R.string.necessario_aceitar_permissoes, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            LogUtil.log(TAG, "onActivityResult(): requestCode[" + requestCode + "], resultCode[" + resultCode + "]");

            if (requestCode == Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_SELECIONAR_ARQUIVO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                LogUtil.log(TAG, "onActivityResult(): SELECIONOU");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                
                final String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), selectedImageUri);
                // here path is always null if pdf file is selected
                File f = null;
                if (path != null) {
                    f = new File(path);
                }

                if (f != null) {
                    String fileExtension = FileUtils.getFileExtension(f.getName());
                    if (tipo.contains("pdf") && !fileExtension.equals("pdf")) {
                        alert(R.string.tipo_de_arquivo_invalido);
                        selecionarArquivo();
                    } else {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        foto.file = f;
                        bundle.putSerializable(Foto.KEY, foto);
                        showForResult(ExemploEFotoActivity.class, bundle, Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRMAR_FOTO);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            alert(R.string.msg_error_foto);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
```

FileUtils.java

```java
public class FileUtils {
 public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("document".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = uri;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A140` That is a nice content scheme uri from the media store provider. Dont try to get a path from it to begin with. Not needed. You did not tell what you want to do with the picked file or/and why you need a path.

Comment: And coming to your subject: `How to choose pdf file from android storage` Well you know exactly how to do that as you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. So i do not understand the subject. It does not cover your problem.

Comment: @blackapps I need to get this file to be able to preview it in another activity. To do that  i need to save the file into a object called foto `foto.file = f;`.

Comment: Add an Uri variable to that object so you can replace that with `foto.uri=data.getData();`

Comment: You can use library https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using this [FileUtils](https://github.com/coltoscosmin/FileUtils/blob/master/FileUtils.java), wich worked perfectly.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Using the above FileUtils, I am still getting the file as null.
Is the solution working?